# Does a class or struct have a default static constructor if not explicitly defined with one?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static, static-constructor

C# specification states that if one does not explicitly define a parameter-less constructor in a class or struct type, then the C# (I assume it's referring to the compiler, correct me if i'm wrong) provides one for them, so that when an instance of the type is created the default parameter-less constructor provided will be used to initialize instance fields to their default values if the instance fields are not intialized at declaration or by any parameterized constructor.

> If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by
> default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the
> default values as listed in the Default values of C# types article. If
> you don't provide a constructor for your struct, C# relies on an
> implicit parameterless constructor to automatically initialize each
> field to its default value.

```
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //invoke default parameter-less constructor belonging to types MyClass and MyStruct
            MyClass inst1 = new MyClass();

            MyStruct inst2 = new MyStruct();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        //body
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
        //body
    }
```

Yet, does the same go static constructors in a class type or struct type? **In the sense that if you do not expliclty define a parameter-less static cosntructor, C# (I assume the compiler, correct me if i'm wrong) will provide one for you by default?** In order to initialize static fields not initialized at declaration or at anypoint during program execution?

C# specification just states

> Static constructors are parameterless. If you don't provide a static
> constructor to initialize static fields, the C# compiler initializes
> static fields to their default value as listed in the Default values
> of C# types article.

The above text doesn't answer the question though. Plus, I have no clue how to test this out in code (as I did with a default non-static parameter-less constructor) since a static constructor cannot be invoked explicitly in code.

Comment: The _default_ field initialization isn't done by the constructor anyway. This seems to be a bit of a moot question.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking this?

Comment: @Llama ok, but does a class or struct have a default static cosntructor if not explicitly defined with one?

Comment: [Seemingly not](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABMugGxGoEDCBA3jgL4477kEAitBXDQA==), but why does it matter?

Comment: @Llama why does it not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter because you're not calling the constructor yourself, and default field initialization isn't performed by the constructor, so it doesn't affect you generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of a static constructor actually matters (a little bit), as said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

> The presence of a static constructor prevents the addition of the `BeforeFieldInit` type attribute. This limits runtime optimization.

This implies that if you don't declare a static constructor, then there is no static constructor automatically generated. Because if there is always a static constructor generated for a class, then that sentence would not make much sense.

We can check by looking at the IL on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/).

- [Without static constructor](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyqoF8g==)
- [With static constructor](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyqrq4dKWYAoAlG07cxorgF8qkoA=)

The extra static constructor is declared in IL as:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
    void .cctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 1 (0x1)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ret
} // end of method C::.cctor
```

Comment: when you say. "Because if there is always a static constructor generated for a class, then that sentence would not make much sense." does the same apply to structs???

Comment: I'd test this out myself but I am not familiar with reading IL code.

Comment: @JaviLangunz The IL for the struct is pretty similar to the one for the class. Just look for `.cctor`. That seems to be the "name" of the static constructor. And to answer your question, yes, this applies for structs too.